# Can't set NSString property in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'm not sure what is going on here but I'm unable pass a string into a view that is being pushed onto a NavigationController.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
InventoryInquiryViewController *listViewController = (InventoryInquiryViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InventoryList"];

[listViewController setItemBalanceRecords: self.itemBalanceRecords];  //this is an NSMutableArray and it works
[listViewController setItemNumber: @"Not Working!"]; //this is an NSString and it remains nil
[self.navigationController pushViewController:listViewController animated:YES];
```

So passing in the array is working as expected by trying to set a simple string property is failing even if I specify a string literal.  I'm out of ideas on this one.

**Edit:**

I've updated the code to remove the issue around description.  The code was shortened as I'm trying to set a couple of string values.  The revised code is still displaying the same behaviour.

**Edit:**

They are declared as properties like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *itemBalanceRecords;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *itemNumber;
```

The application is for internal enterprise use and supports ios7 only.

Comment: make sure you `@syntetize`

Comment: Just rename `description` to something like `itemDescription`.

Comment: Yep, don't use "description" as a property name.

Comment: Code has been updated to remove the issue around description. Same issue still exists.

Comment: Can we have code of .h and .m file where you define ItemBalanceRecords,ItemNumber string.

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming the property from description to something else. Description is an `NSObject` property (which is a superclass for `UIViewController`) and having a property of the same name can cause weird behavior such as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

description is method for all NSObject's subclasses, so you shouldn't use it for your own needs
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description